# Does forcing a refresh of a Firebase ID token invalidate the previous one?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get some user data from my server via a GET request. First I obtain a Firebase ID token on the client:

`const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true /* forces refresh */);`

Then I pass it to the server on authorization headers where it gets verified:

`const user = await getAuth().verifyIdToken(token);`

Once the token gets verified on the server and a response gets sent to the client, is that token invalidated due to the force refresh param? Or is it the case that the next API call will generate a new token but both will still be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firbase Authentication tokens are bearer tokens, meaning they are valid until they expire. There isn't really any built-in way to invalidate that token once it's been minted.

If you want to not allow that token anymore, you'll have to track and check it yourself. There's a good example of this in the documentation on [managing user sessions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation).